# Redux TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form, redux-saga, redux-thunk

I have created a simple website where you can track currencies and add them to your favourite list. I use http://api.nbp.pl/ for that. I was told to use redux for state management. the idea is that you can click on "add to your favourites" button in the MainPage component where all the currencies render and the data is stored in the FavouriteCurrencyList redux store and it renders the chosen currencies (MainPageItem child component) in the Favourites component. I don't know why I keep on receiving the TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined error. The store works ok, when I click on "add to favourite list button" I can see that it passes the information to the list inside the FavouriteCurrencyList as it should (I use redux dev tool extension in chrome browser). However when I want to go to the Favourites tab I receive the aforementioned mistake.

This is the MainPage component where I render all the currencies as a div list:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MainPageItem from "./MainPageItem.js";
import "./MainPage.css";

function MainPage(props) {
  const [mids, setMids] = useState([]);
  const [codes, setCodes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        const mid = data[0].rates.map((currency) => {
          return currency.mid;
        });
        setMids(mid);
      });
  }, []);

  console.log(mids);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        const code = data[0].rates.map((currency) => {
          return currency.code;
        });
        setCodes(code);
      });
  }, []);

  console.log(codes);

  const GetCurrencyRender = React.memo(({ currency, mid }) => {
    return <MainPageItem codes={currency} mids={mid} />;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="main-page">
      <div className="main-page__currecy-list-container">
        <div className="main-page__currency-list">
          {codes.map((code, i) => (
            <MainPageItem key={i} currency={code} mid={mids[i]} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainPage;
```

This is the MainPageItem component where I use the dispatch method:

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import "./MainPageItem.css";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { saveCurrencies } from "../ducks/favouriteCurrencyList";

function MainPageItem(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onClickAddToFavouritesButton = useCallback(() => {
    console.log();
    dispatch(saveCurrencies({ currency: props.currency, mid: props.mid }));
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="item__container">
      <div className="item__currency">{props.currency}</div>
      <div className="item__pln">PLN</div>
      <div className="item__mid">{props.mid}</div>
      <button className="button" onClick={onClickAddToFavouritesButton}>
        Add Currency to Favourites!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainPageItem;
```

This is the FavouriteCurrencyList redux store:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const currencySlice = createSlice({
  name: "list",
  initialState: {
    list: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    saveCurrencies(state, action) {
      const { currency, mid } = action.payload;
      state.list.push({ currency: currency, mid: mid });
    },
  },
});

export const { saveCurrencies } = currencySlice.actions;

export default currencySlice.reducer;
```

This is the FavouriteCurrencyItem component. The only difference between this one and the MainPageItem is the remove button. I have intentions of making a remove button where I give the user an option to delete the currency from the favourite list:

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import "./FavouriteCurrencyItem.css";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { saveCurrencies } from "../ducks/favouriteCurrencyList";

function FavouriteCurrencyItem(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onClickRemoveFavouriteCurrencyButton = useCallback(() => {}, [
    dispatch,
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="favourite-item__container">
      <div className="favourite-item__currency">{props.currency}</div>
      <div className="favourite-item__pln">PLN</div>
      <div className="favourite-item__mid">{props.mid}</div>
      <button className="button" onClick={onClickRemoveFavouriteCurrencyButton}>
        Remove currency from your favourites
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FavouriteCurrencyItem;
```

And this is the Favourites component where the chosen curriencies should render:

```
import React from "react";
import MainPageItem from "../mainPage/MainPageItem";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import "../mainPage/MainPage.css";
import { saveCurrencies } from "../ducks/favouriteCurrencyList";

function Favourites(props) {
  const currencyStore = useSelector((state) => state.list);

  const GetCurrencyRender = React.memo(({ currency, mid }) => {
    return <MainPageItem currency={currency} mid={mid} />;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="main-page">
      list of favourite currencies
      <div className="main-page__currecy-list-container">
        <div className="main-page__currency-list">
          {currencyStore.list.map((currency, mid) => {
            return <GetCurrencyRender currency={currency} mid={mid} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Favourites;
```

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I got that ..

Replace your Reducer name in below line

```
  const currencyStore = useSelector((state) => state["yourReducerName"]);
```

you will get your reducer complete state in currencyStore variable ..and then you can use this store vaiable in dom like that

```
<div className="main-page__currency-list">
          {currencyStore.list.map((currency, mid) => {
            return <GetCurrencyRender currency={currency} mid={mid} />;
          })}
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I just tried what you suggested and unfortunatelly I get exactly the same mistake. But thanks for trying to help!

Comment: In component Favourites. This i where I want to render the child components based on the information gathered in store. when I click on Favourite tab (trying to enter the favourite component) I get this error.

Comment: @WorstProgrammerEver review my answer again I have edited it..hope that will help you